# Algpseudocode (algorithmicx) package comments

Tags: horizontal-alignment, algorithmicx

How to align comments in `algorithmic` environment to the right? For `\Comment`, if the comment is too long it gets wrapped and starts at the beginning of next line. It would look better if it was aligned to the right side.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Function{foo}{x}
\State $x \gets 1$ \Comment{very long comment}
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Wrap the comment inside a `t`op-aligned `\parbox` of specific width. Consider the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \Function{foo}{x}
      \State $x \gets 1$ \Comment{very long comment 
        very long comment very long comment very long comment very long comment
        very long comment very long comment very long comment very long comment
        very long comment very long comment very long comment very long comment
        very long comment very long comment very long comment very long comment.}
      \State $x \gets 1$ \Comment{\parbox[t]{.5\linewidth}{very long comment 
        very long comment very long comment very long comment very long comment
        very long comment very long comment very long comment very long comment
        very long comment very long comment very long comment very long comment
        very long comment very long comment very long comment very long comment.}}
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it automatically use the width available on the first line? So that you don't have to set `0.5\linewidth` and so that it doesn't leave so much space between the equation and the comment?