# Align comments in algorithm with package algorithm2e

Tags: horizontal-alignment, algorithm2e, comments

I am using the package algorithm2e.
When using comments like this

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[algochapter,linesnumbered,ruled,lined,boxed]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \tcp{not aligned comment}
    \If(\tcp*[h]{comment next to if}){constraint}{ 
         c  \tcp*[l]{bla}
         $d = \min \{c,e\}$ \tcp*[l]{minimum}
    }      

\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

the result is

```
// not aligned comment
if constraint then // comment next to if 
   c; // bla
   d = min{c,e}; // minimum
end
```

I would like to have the comments aligned, that is

```
// not aligned comment
if constraint then       // comment next to if
   c;                    // bla
   d = min{c,e};         // minimum
end
```

I only found an answer for the package algorithmicx: [Algpseudocode (algorithmicx) package comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63450/algpseudocode-algorithmicx-package-comments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This flushes them right, padded to the longest comment, so the `//` line up. It takes a couple of runs to get the measuring. I added some `$` to avoid errors that were generated when I tried your MWE.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\makeatletter
\newdimen\commentwd
\let\oldtcp\tcp
\def\tcp*[#1]#2{% only support one style for simplicity
\setbox0\hbox{#2}%
\ifdim\wd\z@>\commentwd\global\commentwd\wd\z@\fi
\oldtcp*[r]{\leavevmode\hbox to \commentwd{\box0\hfill}}}

\let\oldalgorithm\algorithm
\def\algorithm{\oldalgorithm
\global\commentwd\z@
\expandafter\ifx\csname commentwd@\romannumeral\csname c@\algocf@float\endcsname\endcsname\relax\else
\global\commentwd\csname commentwd@\romannumeral\csname c@\algocf@float\endcsname\endcsname
\fi
}
\let\oldendalgorithm\endalgorithm
\def\endalgorithm{\oldendalgorithm
\immediate\write\@auxout{\gdef\expandafter\string\csname commentwd@\romannumeral\csname c@\algocf@float\endcsname\endcsname{%
\the\commentwd}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    c  \tcp*[l]{bla}
    $d = \min \{c,e\}$ \tcp*[l]{minimum}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, now a normal command like \tcp{comment} throws an error. Is it possible to also use regular comments? Edited my question.

Comment: easiest is to change `\def\tcp*[#1]#2` to `\def\mytcp*[#1]#2` or some such then use `\mytcp`.

Comment: This does not work with if-statements, and the font is not the same.

Comment: Ive never used the package just based on your mwe, so don't know about if statement markup, The code I posted does nothing with fonts, oh you might prefer to replace `\box0` by `#2` if the tcp command changes font.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution I'm using with algorithm2e. The idea is to use right-aligned comments (`\tcp*[r]`), and put them in a box of fixed length `\commentWidth`. The important stuff is wrapped in an "aligned comment" macro `\atcp` for ease of use.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[algochapter,linesnumbered,ruled,lined,boxed]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}

\newlength{\commentWidth}
\setlength{\commentWidth}{7cm}
\newcommand{\atcp}[1]{\tcp*[r]{\makebox[\commentWidth]{#1\hfill}}}

\begin{algorithm}
    \tcp{not aligned comment}
    \If(\tcp*[h]{comment next to if}){constraint}{ 
         c  \atcp{bla}
         $d = \min \{c,e\}$ \atcp{minimum}
    }      

\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image: n ima]

I do not know how to align comments after if-style blocks, though.

Comment: You can align the if-style comments by using your own \atcp function instead of \tcp*.

Comment: This is perfect! Note that the `[r]` option after `\tcp*` will automatically insert a newline; So, either omit `\;` from lines ending with the comment, or remove `[r]`, to avoid double-newlines.