# Questions about algpseudocode

Tags: macros, formatting, algorithms, pseudocode

I'm using the following packages:

```
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
```

but I don't understand what package is `algpseudocode`, since I can't find the documentation. I have followed [this page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms). What's the difference between it and `algorithmicx`?

Also, how do I make calls inside a function (e.g. a recursion?) without using `\text{...}` (the font will be different and it does not look like a function). Here is an example:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Function {foo}{$a$}
...
\State \Return \text{foo($a-1$)}
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

And how do I make a new line (for instance if a `\text{...}` is too long)?

Finally, how do I define a `\TRUE` macro (like the `algorithmic` package)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [algpseudocode](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algpseudocode.sty) is part of [`algorithmicx`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx) package, loads `algorithmicx` also.  Excerpt of [algorithmicx's documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf) "The main diﬀerence is that while the algorithmic package doesn’t allow you to modify predeﬁned structures, or to create new ones,the `algorithmicx` package gives you full control over the deﬁnitions". Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63450

Comment: may be something like this `\newcommand{\TRUE}{\textbf{true}}` in preamble as done in `algorithmic.sty` or may be flag based `\algdef` provided by `algorithmicx` for defining macro.

Comment: If `\TRUE` is only a keyword that can appear inside an algorithm, as I suppose, the right definition is `\algnewcommand\TRUE{\textkeyword{true}\space}`

Comment: @texenthusiast If `\TRUE` has to be only a keyword, I don't think `\algdef` is appropriate, since it is used to define blocks and loops commands.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, `\algnewcommand\True{\textbf{true}}` did the trick :)

Comment: @Simon You are right, `\textkeyword` is defined only if you load `algpascal` or `algc`. Anyway, leave `\space` at the end if something can follow `\True`.

Comment: @texenthusiast I think in this case it would be better if Simon wrote his/her own answer... ;-)

Comment: Simon finish the proceedings by summing up all info here as @karlkoeller suggested with a fully compilable code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to the help of texenthusiast and karlkoeller I solved everything.

`algpseudocode` is part of `algorithmicx` package ([documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf)).

For nested function I just did

```
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Function {foo}{$a$}
...
\State \Return \Call{foo}{$a-1$}
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

To split a long line

```
\State \parbox[t]{.7\linewidth}{a very very very very very very very very very very very long line}
```

And for the `\True` macro I added `\algnewcommand\True{\textbf{true}\space}` at the beginning of the document.

Here's a fully compilable code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\algnewcommand\True{\textbf{true}\space}
\algnewcommand\False{\textbf{false}\space}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Function {foo}{$a$}
\State \parbox[t]{.7\linewidth}{a very very very very very very very very very very very long line}
\State \Return \Call{foo}{$a-1$}
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```